# How to add new pure virtual method to class in a migration-friendly way?

Tags: c++, migration, backwards-compatibility

Situation: We have a C++ library "L" with a class `X` that has already some pure virtual methods.  The library "L" provides all derived classes for `X` that are needed in production code - users do not have to create derived classes of `X` themselves.  However, for testing, users of "L" have created derived classes of `X` to mock "L" in their unit-tests.

Problem: `X` shall be extended by adding a new pure virtual method.  It is clear that this breaks binary compatibility of user code, but that is not our concern.  We only strive for source code compatibility of user code.  This source code compatibility of user code is granted for *production code*.  However, the unit-tests of the users break, because their mock classes that are derived from the changed `X` can no longer be instantiated.

We are looking for a way to introduce the new method in a migration friendly way that does avoid breaking user code - be it production code or test code.  In other scenarios where interfaces changed we used the common approach to have two steps: first deprecate some function, then remove it in a later release.  That is, we are willing to take an approach that involves more than one step.

For example, we were thinking about adding the new method as non-pure at first (still allowing the derived mock classes to be instantiated), and make the new method pure later.  However, those users who do not anyway want to use the new method would not get any indication that their test classes need adaptation: There does not seem to be a way to mark a method in a way that indicates "the use as a non-pure function is deprecated".

We are aware of some approaches to solve such problems:

- A new class derived from `X`could be created to hold the pure new virtual method, such that users of the new method would derive from that ([Extending a class and maintaining binary backward compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459504/extending-a-class-and-maintaining-binary-backward-compatibility)).
- We could provide - for mocking purposes - some class `XMockBase` which is derived from `X` and has some default implementation for each method, such that implementers of mock classes would not derive from `X` but rather from `XMockBase`.

We may in the end take one of those approaches.  But, before going in such a direction we would like to know:

Is there any migration friendly approach that can be used to introduce the new method into the existing class?

Comment: [`[[deprecated]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/deprecated)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Won't do anything if the user isn't actually using the new function.

Comment: @user17732522 oh right. Now I get the problem ;)

Comment: though one could declare the whole type as `[[deprecated("if you inherit from this, you will need to override a pure virtual method at some point (which for the time being is not pure)")]]`

Comment: Instead of adding `void new_member_function() = 0;` to `X`, why not create a `struct XWithNewFeature : X { void new_member_function() = 0; }`? It seems like you are adding new functionality anyway which warrants a new class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
namespace TheLibrary {
#if !defined(USE_OLD_BOB_API)
  inline
#endif
  namespace v2 {
    struct Bob {
      virtual ~Bob() {}
      virtual int CountAlices() const = 0;
      virtual int CountCharlies() const = 0;
    };
  }
#if defined(USE_OLD_BOB_API)
  inline
#endif
  namespace v1 {
    struct
    [[deprecated( "Update Bob to v2" )]]
    Bob: TheLibrary::v2::Bob {
      virtual int CountAlices() const final {
        return 0;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

If you include this with `USE_OLD_BOB_API` defined, `TheLibrary::Bob` refers to a `[[deprecated]]` class with only `CountAlices` as a pure-virtual function, and `CountCharlies` has a `final` default implementation.  So existing code has compile time compatibility.

If you include this without `USE_OLD_BOB_API` defined, `TheLibrary::Bob` refers to a `Bob` with a pure virtual `CountCharlies`.

So you'll get a `[[deprecated]]` warning in the code, but it won't otherwise break.

Logic to define `USE_OLD_BOB_API` is pretty standard versioning macro stuff I think: you'll ask them to define a `THELIBRARY_VERSION_NUMBER` macro; if THAT is undefined, it will use the oldest version of your API.

Code can still directly access the specific versions of `Bob` even after they have updated the library version, in case they are doing a partial update.  So if there are 3 such classes, they can bump the version number up, get the new APIs, and manually put in `TheLibrary::v1::Bob` because they are going to get around to `Bob` last.

So long as they are using old versions of `Bob` they'll be `deprecated`.

Now, the real problem is that your customers will insist on compling with warnings as errors.  And you cannot communicate a non-fatal error when they do so.

---

Dirk has incidated he didn't understand how to map `USE_OLD_BOB_API` to a concrete case, so I'll do it.

```
#ifndef THELIBRARY_VERSION_NUMBER
  #define THELIBRARY_VERSION_NUMBER 1 // if not provided, default to old version
#endif

#ifndef THELIBRARY_NOWARNINGS
  #define THELIBRARY_VERBOSE_CODE(...)
#else
  #define THELIBRARY_VERBOSE_CODE(...) __VA_ARGS__
#endif


#if THELIBRARY_VERSION_NUMBER == 1
  #define THELIBRARY_BOB_VERSION 1
#else
  #define THELIBRARY_BOB_VERSION 2
#endif

namespace TheLibrary {
#if THELIBRARY_BOB_VERSION==2
  inline
#endif
  namespace v2 {
    struct Bob {
      // current Bob interface
    };
  }
#if THELIBRARY_BOB_VERSION==1
  inline
#endif
  namespace v1 {
    struct
    THELIBRARY_VERBOSE_CODE([[deprecated( "Update Bob to v2" )]])
    Bob: TheLibrary::v2::Bob {
      // implementations of pure-virtual methods
      // in v2 but missing in v1
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Good idea in principle (+1) - will nevertheless break clients' unit-testing builds at first, that is, requires them to `#define USE_OLD_BOB_API`: Without this `#define`, their mock classes derived from Bob can not be instantiated.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann Please read paragraph 5, starting with "Logic".  You request them to #define THELIBRARY_VERSION_NUMBER macro of some kind to request a specific library version.  You write code that turns that into whatever tokens you need to include/not include the `inline`s above, including "if not defined, give them the oldest version".  I think that code is very simple, but exactly how it works is going to be a matter of taste, so I didn't write it for you, and simply described what it should do.  Do you think you'd have difficulty writing that code?

Comment: Thanks, yes, your extended example makes it clearer.  Switching to a generic versioning macro scheme which -  if not defined - defaults to version 1 would avoid a breaking change.  Sorry for being a bit dense.

Comment: @DirkHerrmann I mean, I don't know if you know how to write macros!  :)  You should see some of the abominations I have to deal with in a larger project - like DLLEXPORT(Token) which expands to non-empty string if and only if Token is **not** defined.  My point was that nothing like that is required here!

Comment: @Yakk-Adam-Nevraumont: Thanks a lot, everything is clear now :-)